# 'beacons' array in cordova-plugins-ibeacon is always empty

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, ibeacon

I am trying to get this plugin to work.

https://github.com/petermetz/cordova-plugin-ibeacon

I am using Cordova cli v8.

I am using a Jaalee iBeacon: https://www.jaalee.com/store

iB004-N plus

I can access this beacon with the manufacturer's app (eBeacon for iOS) and get it to beep. I have the uuid, major and minor numbers.

When I run the plugin here, it does run without any errors but the beacons array is always empty even though the beacon is sitting on my desk beside my Android 7 phone.

Bluetooth is turned on, the iBeacon has been beeped today, location is turned on, and the app has permission to use the location.

Edit: I tried this on iOS and it works but not on Android.

Here's my code:

app.js

```
var identifier = 'jaalee';
var uuid = 'ebefd083-70a2-47c8-9837-e7b5634df524';
var minor = 1;
var major = 1;
var beaconRegion = null;

var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);

        document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", start);
        document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener("click", stop);
    },

    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // Bind any cordova events here. Common events are:
    // 'pause', 'resume', etc.
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        this.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },

    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
        beaconRegion = new cordova.plugins.locationManager.BeaconRegion(identifier, uuid, major, minor);
        console.log(' beaconRegion ', beaconRegion);
    }
};

app.initialize();

function logToDom(message) {
    var e = document.createElement('label');
    e.innerText = message;

    var br = document.createElement('br');
    var br2 = document.createElement('br');
    document.body.appendChild(e);
    document.body.appendChild(br);
    document.body.appendChild(br2);

    window.scrollTo(0, window.document.height);
}

function start() {

    console.log(' start ');

    var delegate = new cordova.plugins.locationManager.Delegate();

    delegate.didDetermineStateForRegion = function (pluginResult) {
        console.log('didDetermineStateForRegion: ', pluginResult);
        logToDom('[DOM] didDetermineStateForRegion: ' + JSON.stringify(pluginResult));

        cordova.plugins.locationManager.appendToDeviceLog('[DOM] didDetermineStateForRegion: '
            + JSON.stringify(pluginResult));
    };

    delegate.didStartMonitoringForRegion = function (pluginResult) {
        console.log('didStartMonitoringForRegion:', pluginResult);

        logToDom('didStartMonitoringForRegion:' + JSON.stringify(pluginResult));
    };

    delegate.didRangeBeaconsInRegion = function (pluginResult) {
        console.log('didRangeBeaconsInRegion: ', pluginResult);
        logToDom('[DOM] didRangeBeaconsInRegion: ' + JSON.stringify(pluginResult));
    };

    cordova.plugins.locationManager.setDelegate(delegate);

    // required in iOS 8+
    cordova.plugins.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization();
    // or cordova.plugins.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    console.log(' beaconRegion ', beaconRegion);

    cordova.plugins.locationManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegion)
        .fail(function(e) { console.log(e); })
        .done();

}

function stop() {

    console.log(' stop ');

    cordova.plugins.locationManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegion)
        .fail(function(e) { console.log(e); })
        .done();

}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
            <button id="start">start</button>
            <button id="stop">stop</button>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tested on other devices? do you have the same problem on iOS? also, you can simulate a beacon with your devices and use the device as a beacon and see if it works with the simulated beacon.

Comment: Also, make sure your beacon's UUID matches the UUID you set in your app.

Comment: Yes, the uuids match. I ran it on a different Android device and I got the same result. The plugin won't run on iOS I keep getting errors such as: uuid.match is not a function (this is from BeaconRegion.js)

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to work on iOS now. But it does not work on Android.

Comment: Check permission with `getAuthorizationStatus` method on the Android device and make sure you have the right permission!!

Comment: I don't know how to use that function but I looked in settings and it says location is permitted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170088/discussion-between-user1261710-and-mrfrhn).